# Como ler um arquivo Json

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var json = [{
    bloco:"bloco1",
    titulo: "titulo1",
    perguntas: [{
        pergunta1: "Resposta1",
        opcaoSelecionada: "2"
            }];
}/*,{
    bloco:"bloco2",
    titulo: "titulo2",
    perguntas: [{
        pergunta2: "Resposta2",
        opcaoSelecionada: "2"
            }];*/
];    
//var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);

    alert(JSON.stringify(json));
    //alert(obj.bloco);
});
```

Eu estou aprendendo Json, e gostaria de saber se essa estrutura está construída corretamente. A ideia é guardar todas as informações dentro de um `array` de objetos, que serão gerados à partir de dados preenchidos no front.

Depois irei mandar essa informação via Ajax para o PHP montar uma estrutura para exibir os dados. Poderiam também me falar como eu leria esse arquivo no PHP/javascript com um loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A notação do JSON é bastante semelhante ao de um objeto no Javascript, salvo algumas poucas diferênças:

**Objeto Javascript:**

```
[
    {
       "bloco":"bloco1",    // Uso de aspas duplas 
       'titulo': "titulo1", // aspas simples é
       perguntas: [{        // opcional
          pergunta1: "Resposta1",
          opcaoSelecionada: 2 // Valores numéricos são permitido
       }], // Não se usa ; no final de um elemento nem para separar-los
       callback: function(){ alert('Hello World!'); }
    }
]
```

Uma notação de objeto no Javascript é bem flexível e simples. Você ainda pode adicionar outros elementos após a criação do objeto:

```
objeto[ 'chave' ] = 'Valor';
objeto[ 'outra' ] = {name: 'Objeto Filho', value: 'Outro valor' };
```

**JSON:**

```
[
    {
       "bloco":"bloco1",    // Uso de aspas duplas é obrigatório
       "titulo": "titulo1", // aspas simples não é permitido
       "perguntas": [{
          "pergunta1": "Resposta1",
          "opcaoSelecionada": 2 // Valores numéricos são permitido
       }] // Não se usa ; no final de um elemento nem para separar-los
       // Não é permitido funções
    }
]
```

Você pode enviar os seus dados como objeto pelo `$.ajax`, e recebe-los como campos de formulários no PHP

```
var dados = [
  {
    bloco: "bloco1", titulo: "titulo1", perguntas: [
      {pergunta: "Pergunta1", opcao: 2},
      {pergunta: "Pergunta2", opcao: 1},
      {pergunta: "Pergunta3", opcao: 4}
    ]
  }
]

$.ajax({
  url: '/path/to/file',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {blocos: dados},
  success: function(data){
    alert(data.msg);
  }, 
  error: console.log
});
```

No PHP pode receber os dados como variáveis POST, como informado na propriedade `type` do `ajax`:

```
$blocos = (!empty($_POST['blocos']) ? $_POST['blocos'] : NULL);

$msg = '';

foreach ($blocos as $bloco) {
    $msg .= "Bloco: $bloco['bloco'] <br>\n".
            "Título: $bloco['titulo'] <br>\n";

    foreach ($bloco['perguntas'] as $pergunta) {
        $msg .= "Pergunta: $pergunta['pergunta'] <br>\n".
                "Resposta: $pergunta['opcao'] <br>\n";
    }

    $msg .= "<br>\n<br>\n";

}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(
    Array( 
        'msg' => $msg 
    )
);
exit;
```

Você também pode enviar os dados como uma *string* e decodifica-la como a função `json_decode`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/path/to/file',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {blocos: JSON.stringify(dados)},
  success: function(data){
    alert(data.msg);
  }, 
  error: console.log
});
```

Quando se manda o objeto diretamente no parâmetro `data` do `$.ajax`, o jQuery se encarrega de tratar esses dados corretamente. 
Mas quando você transforma o objeto em uma *string* no formato JSON utilizando `JSON.stringify(dados)` 
é necessário decodificar essa *string* no PHP:

```
<?php

    $blocos = (!empty($_POST['blocos']) ? json_decode($_POST['blocos']) : NULL);
```

Answer (score 3):

O PHP tem uma função chamada [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$matriz = array();
$matriz = json_decode($json);
```

que passa json para um array. nunca testei mas deve funcionar , no caso se o json estiver bem construído mas se experimentar com a funçãoo que te disse e tudo de certo, com o código abaixo você pode verificar como esta a estrutura e ver se te agrada.

```
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($matriz);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Para ler um arquivo JSON com JavaScript você pode usar a função `jQuery.getJSON`:

```
$.getJSON( "caminho_do_arquivo/arquivo.json", function( data ) {
    // processe os dados aqui
});
```

A documentação completa do método `jQuery.getJSON` se encontra na página http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/